# Authorization in ASP.Net Core 3.1 Web API not working

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 and Angular 11 application with Role-Based Authorization but when run the Application, I get error 401 Unauthorized.

this is my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection"));
        });
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;

        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
           .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        #region JWT Config
        // configure strongly typed settings objects
        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["ApplicationSettings:JWT_Secret"].ToString());

        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = false;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
        });
        #endregion
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
    }
```

this is Configure function

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
      
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseCors(x => x.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials());
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
```

this is my Controller class, I have appropriate Authorize attribute like so,

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class CharitiesController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

this is record of admin in applicationuser table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghBlu.png)

this record of admin role in applicationrole table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZX9d.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihgjb.png)

Comment: In role table NormalizedName role name is really not normalized. And it will be helpful if you provide logs

Comment: @IlnarGabidullin i get ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":401,"statusText":"OK","url":"https://localhost:44369/Charities/GetCharities","ok":false,

Comment: First of all try to fix normalized name. Use RoleManager<RoleClass>  to create new role, or if you insert role manually use "admin".Normalize().ToUpperInvariant(); to set value of RoleClass.NormalizedName

Comment: @MostafaGomaa, from the configuration, you use jwt authentication as the default scheme, but where do you  put the token when send the request? And how do you put the claim, can you share the relevant code?